# How do I keep the Locals IDE window always on top while debugging?

Tags: ide, window, local-variables

I found a few posts that explain how to keep a programmatically created window always on top.
I was unable however to find an explanation about how to keep always on top the IDE integrated Locals window, while I am debugging (I run the program with F10 for instance).
I see that there is no answer in a long time, so I realize that my question is not expressed clearly enough. I shall clarify.
Usually, while debugging, the active window is the IDE and so also the control keys (F10, F11 and so on) are also active. In the same time, the Locals window is on top and so one may watch the values of the variables while debugging.
In my case,while the IDE window is active, the Locals window is hidden and in order to see the Locals window, I have to press its tab on the status bar. when the Locals window appears (becomes active) and the values of the variables are visible, the IDE window becomes hidden and the control keys ate not active anymore. I have to press the tab of the IDE window on the taskbar in order to resume debugging.
Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: @Robert Moore Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your locals panel is auto-hiding as is your main code panel, or are they actually in separate windows? Assuming the same window but differing panels...

There should be a dropdown option with pin or auto-hide or float, you may also find that dragging the locals window (by titlebar) to another panel that remains open to be a better option, or drag it to be a floating window and resize the IDE to be 3/4 of screen and locals to the remaining 1/4. The final option is to close the locals window and reopen a new one using the Debug menu and then experiment with new positioning and docking options.

One last resort may be to reset the window layout to default and get back to the way it should be setup.

Good luck and let us know how you fare.

Comment: @Thank you very much. As a matter of fact I found out about the auto-hide and turned it to pin the window before I had a chance to check your answer, but your answer is correct. Thank you again.